# jQuery if div has a class of 'in' change another div's background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the background of a div class `.panel-heading` to blue if the `.panel-collapse` inside the div `.panel` has a class of `in`. I am using Bootstrap accordion.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                Lipsum set dolor
                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end panel -->
```

I tried something simple like this but it is not working:

```
if ($('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
    $(this).closest('.panel-heading').css("background", "blue");
}
else {
    $(this).closest('.panel-heading').css("background", "red");
}
```

Comment: what is the `this` there?

Comment: this would be the current panel's '.panel-collapse' as there would be numerous panels on the page and if i remove the $(this) part it would make all panels panel-heading to blue

Comment: @AlexZahir He is asking in which context does the "this" exists

Comment: made a fiddle here if there is any confusion. the context should be clearer that way: http://jsfiddle.net/ru9Lzw5p/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.panel-heading` is sibling of `.panel-collapse`. Try like following using <kbd>[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)</kbd> method.

```
$('.in').siblings('.panel-heading').css("background", "blue");

$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    var panelHeading = $(this).siblings('.panel-heading');
    panelHeading.find(".glyphicon-plus").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus");
    panelHeading.css("background", "blue");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    var panelHeading = $(this).siblings('.panel-heading');
    panelHeading.find(".glyphicon-minus").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus");
    panelHeading.css("background", "red");
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ru9Lzw5p/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.panel-collapse').each(function(index,element){
    if($(element).hasClass('in')){
        $(element).prev('.panel-heading').css("background", "blue");
    } else {
        $(element).prev('.panel-heading').css("background", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

Cordialy
Frederic

Comment: okay this works in showing the panel-collapse with a class of 'in' to have a background of blue on page load. But when the next panel is clicked and it is active (meaning it now has the class of 'in' and the class of 'in' has been removed from the first panel) it's background does not seem to become blue. So I am thinking maybe add a on click function to your code?

Comment: To understand what i mean, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ru9Lzw5p/6/

Try clicking on the panels to see what i mean. the background color remains unchanged. it should change to whoever has the 'in' class.

Answer (score 0):

ok, donc :

```
$(function(){

    $('.accordion-toggle').on('click',function(e){
    $('.panel-heading').removeClass('bgBlue');
    $(this).closest('div.panel-heading').addClass('bgBlue');
  });

});
```

in css add :

```
.bgBlue{
  background-color:blue !important;
}
```

and it's work, i hope it's what you want ,-)
Frederic

Comment: you must remove : 
 
if ($('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').css("background", "blue");
}
else {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').css("background", "red");
}